# Uso do EOF em vetores

Tags: c

Boa noite, gostaria de saber se nesse programa estou usando o EOF(end of file) direito, ou seja, enquanto eu não digitar 0, o vetor vai sendo alocado e gravado com um valor??
Segue codigo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i,j, counter = 1,mediaaritmetica, novasequencia;
    int* sequencia = NULL;

    while (scanf(%d), &sequencia[i] != EOF)
    {
        sequencia = (int*) realloc(sequencia, counter * sizeof(int));
        scanf("%d", &sequencia[i]);
        counter++
    }   

    for (j = 0; j < counter ; j++)
    {
        mediaartimetica += sequencia[j];
    }

    mediaaritmetica = mediaartimetica/counter - 1;

    for ( k = 2, k < counter ; k++)
    {
        novasequencia = pow(sequencia[k], 2)/mediaaritmetica * (sequencia[k - 2] + sequencia[k -1] + sequencia[k])
        printf(".4%d\n", novasequencia);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O código que você apresentou nem compila ainda. Acho que tem margem pra você acertar bastante coisa antes de atacar o problema do EOF. :)

Answer (score 1):

Algumas notas:

1. `while (scanf(%d), &sequencia[i] != EOF)` erro de aspas e parentesis
2. `sequencia = NULL; /* ... */ &sequencia[i]` estas a por o carro a frente dos bois
3. uso de `i` sem lhe atribuir um valor
4. `mediaaritmetica = mediaartimetica/counter - 1;` precisa de parentesis
5. `pow()` precisa de `<math.h>`. Mas podes fazer o mesmo multiplicando o valor: `sequencia[k] * sequencia[k]`
6. identificadores diferentes!!! `mediaaritmetica` e `mediaartimetica`

Answer (score 0):

O `EOF` é usado apenas para quando se mexe com arquivos, assim como o nome já diz `End Of File`, final do arquivo, não do vetor.

Começando com o seu `while`, o `scanf` é um método que para a leitura de informação e o `sequencia[i]` ainda não existe, e as condições em um `while` out qualquer outra estrutura se separa com `&&` ou `||` (isso em C,C++,etc). O correto é ter uma variável para recolher o valor do `scanf` e através dela verificar a entrada.

```
int in = 1;
sequencia = (int*) malloc(0);
// continua enquanto 'in' diferente de '0'
while(in != 0){
    scanf("%i", &in);                     // counter deve iniciar em 0 para
                                          // não ter problema no for abaixo.
    sequencia = (int*) realloc(sequencia, (couter + 1)*sizeof(int));
    sequencia[counter] = in;
    counter++;
}
```

Outro coisa, primeiro de um `malloc` em `sequencia`.

Sua média tem que ter parenteses em `counter - 1` para retirar um antes da divisão.

```
mediaaritmetica = mediaartimetica/(counter - 1);
```

E por fim, você deve declarar `k` antes de usá-lo no `for`.

```
int k;
for ( k = 2, k < counter ; k++){
```

e todas as outras variáveis inicie com 0, pois quando uma variável é criada, o compilador insere lixo de valor nelas.

```
int i,j, counter = 1,mediaaritmetica=0, novasequencia=0;
```